# Processing WordPress 3rd party plugin admin page HTML

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

For front facing WP pages I use the `the_content` filter to pre-process the HTML by using either regex or `DOMDocument()` in order to, for example, prepare inline images for a lazyload script.

Is there an equivalent filter I can use to alter a plugin's admin page's HTML?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reference, there is no equivalent to `the_content` in regards to a 3rd party plugin's admin page's HTML.

Plugins output their admin HTML using the custom [{$page_hook}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_hook/) action.

For anybody interested, also take a look at the `\wp-admin\admin.php` file, the [load-{$page_hook}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/) action and the [get_plugin_page_hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hook/) function.